# Target link to iframe on table row click

Tags: html, iframe, flask, html-table

I am trying to pass a specific link to an `<iframe>` when clicking a row on my HTML table. With the code on the bottom, it simply opens the link in the window instead of opening it in the specified iframe.

Using a normal `<a>` HTML link tags, it works when I use `href="" onclick="this.href='/query/{{index}}'" target="iframe_b"` but nothing happens when I use this with `<tr>` tags.

```
...

   <table class='hoverTable'>
         {% for index, value in list.items() %}
            <tr href='' onclick="location.href='/query/{{index}}'" target="iframe_b">
               <th> {{ index }} </th>
               <td> {{ value }} </td>
            </tr>
         {% endfor %}
   </table>

...

<div style="float:right; width: 69.9%;height: 1050px;">
    <div align="left">
        <iframe height="800px" width="100%" name="iframe_b"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<iframe height="800px" width="100%" name="iframe_b" id="iframe_b"></iframe>
```

And then:

```
<tr href='' onclick="document.getElementById('iframe_b').src='/query/{{index}}'" target="iframe_b">
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!